# unable to understand the address and cmd in ADS7830 chip

Tags: i2c

I am trying to understand a code written in `RaspberryPi` to use analog to digital converter chip `ADS7830`. The datasheet is at

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads7830.pdf

At page 13, the data sheet says the address should be `10010` plus value of `A1`,`A0` and `R/w`.

When I run command `i2cdetect -y 1` to detect `ADS7830`, I see address `0x4b` which corresponds to binary `01001011`. But this pattern doesn't match `10010A0A1R/W` as per page 13. I tried other values by grounding pins `A0` and `A1` and I saw values `48` for example when both `A0` and `A1` are grounded but that is `0x48` equivalent to `01001000`. This also doesn't match with the pattern as per page 13.

Question 1 - why is address of `ADS7830` `4b`?

Question 2 -
The code I am trying to understand is

````
    def __init__(self):
        super(ADS7830, self).__init__()
        self.cmd = 0x84 <-- FROM WHERE THIS VALUE COMES FROM. NOT CLEAR TO ME IN DATASHEET
   
        self.address = 0x4b # 0x4b is the default i2c address for ADS7830 Module.
        
    def analogRead(self, chn): # ADS7830 has 8 ADC input pins, chn:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
        value = self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, self.cmd|(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4))
        return value```

How is the value of `cmd` calculated. What is `cmd`?

Question3 - how is this value calculated for channel 0? `self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, self.cmd|(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4))`. It is not clear from datasheet.
````

Comment: The address disconnect you see is because when you send the address byte over I2C, you must bitshift it by one to the left and add your R/W bit. Thus a device with I2C address 0x4b (01001011) is sent a W message using the byte (10010111) and a R message using the byte (10010110).

Comment: As to your next two questions, the answer is in the explanation of the command byte in the datasheet, also page 13. If you read that through it explains what each bit in the 'cmd' value is actually doing and will answer your remaining questions. Try to get through it yourself - once you can prove you've tried that, if you have more specific questions add them to your post.

Comment: on `cmd` (`0x84` = `10000100` ), the only new part I could understand is channel selection. As I am using channel 0, the `c2-c0` is `000`. But I don't conceptually know what is `SD`, `PD1` and `PD0`. The 2 LSBs are not used anyhow.

Comment: I found this documentation on `smbus2` (not `smbus` which I am using but I suppose they are similar. https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/smbus2/latest/smbus2.pdf The `read_byte_data(i2c_addr, register, force=None)` refers to a register whose value is calculated as `self.cmd|(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4`. If I calculated correct, `self.cmd|(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4` is same as `self.cmd` as `(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4` should be `0` for channel 0. Again, I can't figure out this logic. The datasheet doesn't refer to any registers.

Comment: Good job on the channel selection part. SD, P1/P0 are also explained conceptually there but I can break it down for you. The SD bit sets the ADC to take in differential inputs or single ended inputs. [Explanation of differential vs. single-ended inputs](https://www.apogeeinstruments.com/differential-vs-single-ended-measurements/). PD1/PD0 set the power down settings of the internal reference voltage and the ADC , and the different options are explained in Table 1 on page 13 of the datasheet. 0x84: Single ended input on channel 0, turn the internal reference voltage off and the ADC on.

Comment: thanks for pushing me :). What about he logic going into `read_byte_data`. the leftshifts and the right shifts and the logical `AND`.

Comment: read_byte_data takes a variable channel (_chn_), so if you pass analogRead() channel 0 then yes it will be self.cmd=0x84 which just happens to be the default command in init(), but if you pass it channel 1 it will be self.cmd=0x94, or 0xA4 for channel 2, and so on. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Classic I2C confusion between two different address notations. The addresses really do match. 0x48 or 0x4B are the 7-bit notation without the read/write bit, corresponding to addresses in 8-bit notation of write addresses 0x90 or 0x96. The bit patterns are identical, 1001000X or 1001011X where X is the read/write bit that can be omitted.

The 0x84 command byte is explained also on page 13 and 14. 10000100 means you want to do single-ended conversion of channel 0 and set internal reference off and turn on the AD converter.

Answer (score 1):

Time for a frame challenge.

Why are you writing this communication code *at all*?

The ADS7830 is supported by the Linux kernel, at least in 5.15 (that's what I checked, didn't bother looking earlier).

What you need is to look at the [device tree bindings](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.48/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/hwmon/ti,ads7828.yaml) and write yourself a device tree overlay. Let the kernel handle it.

Unless you actually need to use features of that ADC which are not available in the kernel.